# Batch file commands - Findstr, splitting and file name variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I'm kind of new to batch commands and have been trying to automate something we do manually. I have a log file that is downloaded every day, then I search for certain items in it using Findstr (output to another file) and then split what was found into smaller files.

I'm having trouble with making file names and file name variables and using it throughout my code. The splitter code was given to me, so I'm just trying to incorporate Findstr into it. Any tips or see what I'm doing wrong?

Example:

> ```
> Campaign ID: 1234
> Campaign Name: Pepsi
> Impression Filename: 10-06-16_file.log
> Day of week: 2
> ```

It will look through `10-06-16_file.log` for any rows with Campaign ID `1234` and output them to `fnd_10-06-16_file.log`.

If `fnd_10-06-16_file.log` filesize is greater than 177000kb then split the file into smaller files with name `2SplitFile1_Pepsi.log`, `2SplitFile2_Pepsi.log`, `2SplitFile3_Pepsi.log`, etc.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off

REM Ask for Campaign information to find
SET /P campaignid="Campaign ID(s): "
SET /P campaignname="Campaign Name: "
SET /P impressionfile="Impression Filename: "
SET /P dayofweek="Day of week: "

SET fnd_impressionfile=%campaignname%_%impressionfile%
SET maxbytesize=177000
SET fnd_impressionfile_sz=%%~zfnd_impressionfile


REM Find campaigns inside log file
findstr "%campaignname%" %impressionfile% > %fnd_impressionfile%


REM Split log file if greater than 177000 kb
if fnd_impressionfile_sz > maxbytesize (

    REM Edit this value to change the name of the file that needs splitting. Include the extension.
    SET BFN=%fnd_impressionfile%
    REM Edit this value to change the number of lines per file.
    SET LPF=1000000
    REM Edit this value to change the name of each short file. It will be followed by a number indicating where it is in the list.
    SET SFN=SplitFile

    REM Do not change beyond this line.

    SET SFX=%BFN:~-3%

    SET /A LineNum=0
    SET /A FileNum=1

    For /F "delims=" %%l in (%BFN%) Do (
        SET /A LineNum+=1

        echo %%l >> %dayofweek%%SFN%!FileNum!_%campaignname%.%SFX%

        if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
            SET /A LineNum=0
            SET /A FileNum+=1
            )

        )
)

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the size of the impression file with this code: `SET fnd_impressionfile_sz=%%~zfnd_impressionfile`.  If so, that is not how it works.  You need to use the FOR command to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, change `SET fnd_impressionfile_sz=%%~zfnd_impressionfile` to `FOR %%a in (%fnd_impressionfile%) DO SET fnd_impressionfile_sz=%%~za`

Then, double check you maxbytesize. Your description says kb, but the batch implies byte. fnd_impressionfile_sz contains the byte value.

The other thing I see is there you're using the redirection operator > in `if fnd_impressionfile_sz > maxbytesize`. You should change it to `GTR` or `GEQ`. See `HELP IF`.